# Mapstruct and InteliJ - Exception sometimes with inherited fields during `build project`

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, mapstruct

### Problem:

We have a class that extends another class and inherits some fields.
`clean install` in maven is working perfectly and the `impl` mapper classes are being generated.

Sometimes other people (students, etc) have changed the mappers, I notice that the `build/make project` in InteliJ is breaking.

I am getting an error such as the following stacktrace:

```
    Error:(12, 8) java: Internal error in the mapping processor: java.lang.NullPointerException            at
 org.mapstruct.ap.internal.model.source.SourceReference.copyForInheritanceTo(SourceReference.java:333)  at
 org.mapstruct.ap.internal.model.source.Mapping.copyForInheritanceTo(Mapping.java:462)      at
 org.mapstruct.ap.internal.model.source.MappingOptions.applyInheritedOptions(MappingOptions.java:279)     at
 org.mapstruct.ap.internal.processor.MapperCreat
ionProcessor.mergeInheritedOptions(MapperCreat
ionProcessor.java:457)                  at
 org.mapstruct.ap.internal.processor.MapperCreat
ionProcessor.getMappingMethods(MapperCreat
ionProcessor.java:274)                  at
 org.mapstruct.ap.internal.processor.MapperCreat
ionProcessor.getMapper(MapperCreat
ionProcessor.java:152)                  at
 org.mapstruct.ap.internal.processor.MapperCreat
ionProcessor.process(MapperCreat
ionProcessor.java:123)                  at
 org.mapstruct.ap.internal.processor.MapperCreat
ionProcessor.process(MapperCreat
ionProcessor.java:80)                  at
 org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor.process(MappingProcessor.java:280)    at
 org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor.processMapperTypeElement(MappingProcessor.java:260)              at
 org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor.processMapperElements(MappingProcessor.java:226)      at
 org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor.process(MappingProcessor.java:162)         at
 com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:794)         at
 com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:705)                  at
 com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1800(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:91)                  at
 com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1035)          at
 com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1176)      at
 com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotat
ions(JavaCompiler.java:1170)  at
 com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:856)              at
 com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:523)                at
 com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:129)  at
 com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:138)         at
```

And here is where jetbrains part is:

```
 org.jetbrains.jps.javac.JavacMain.compile(JavacMain.java:190)                 at
 org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.compileJava(JavaBuilder.java:483)             at
 org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.compile(JavaBuilder.java:339)     at
 org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.doBuild(JavaBuilder.java:256)      at
 org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:214)           at
 org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runModuleLevelBuilders(IncProjectBuilder.java:1263)  at
 org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:940)            at
 org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:1012)               at
 org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:903)           at
 org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:736)              at
 org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:384)      at
 org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:192)             at
 org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:138)                  at
 org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:295)                  at
 org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:125)            at
 org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:236)               at
 org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl.lambda$executeOnPooledThread$0(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:42)                  at
 java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)       at
 java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)            at
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)     at
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)     at
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

### Question:

So, is there some type of configuration change I need to make to InteliJ???

### Current Workaround:

What is working for me now, is to go to the `Spring Boot Run Configuration` and in the section `Before Launch: Activate tool window` I have made a change.

I have removed `Build Project`. So the `target directory` generated from maven is used. Inteli J make command is used only to rebuild and hotswap changed classes.

Comment: does invalidating cache of intelliJ help there?

Comment: Bug report with the reproducible test case would be appreciated at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA if the issue still occurs in the current release.

Comment: First I would recommend to test the build on plain command line...to be sure at the first step the issue is not related to IDE...afterwards Test in IDE...

Comment: thanks for the comments, I will definitely try these suggestions asap in order to test them and also submit a issue to jetbrains.

Comment: Which version of MapStruct are you using? This looks similar as [#1180](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1180). It is strange though that it is happening only within the IntelliJ build. This can happen when you are extending Mappers or using `@MapperConfig` that is in a different jar.

Comment: Can confirm that the workaround provided in the question itself DOES WORK. Thanks @OptimalPrime